# Rails ActiveRecord - Performance - How to destroy invalid belongs_to records

Tags: query-optimization, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have two models:

- Asset has_many Assethistories
- Assethistory belongs_to Asset

Unfortunately, when the migration was created, no foreign_key was added to Assethistories.  Some Assethistories records exist where Assethistories.asset_id has a value that does not exist in Asset.id (probably someone used delete on the Asset table instead of destroy).

There are approximately 10 million Asset records and 25 million Assethistories records.

Using this query takes a VERY LONG time:

```
Assethistory.where("asset_id NOT IN (select id from assets)").delete_all
or in rails syntax:
Assethistory.where.not(asset_id: Asset.select(:id)).delete_all
```

NOTE: we can use delete_all since there are no callbacks or nested models.

In fact, just doing a COUNT of the invalid records takes VERY LONG.

```
Assethistory.where.not(asset_id: Asset.select(:id)).count
```

Is there any way to destroy the invalid records that would be more performant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got some data which is about 20x smaller than your case, e.g 5M `assethistory` and 500K `asset` like your case, which could reproduce your issue by using `where.not`. By following `Anti-Join` pattern, where joins records that don't exist, would bring you the result you want with better performance.

```
Assethistory.left_outer_joins(:asset).where(assets: { id: nil })
# => 3500 rows (415.3ms)
```

or

```
Assethistory.where('NOT EXISTS (:assets)', assets: Asset.select('1').where('assets.id = assethistories.asset_id'))
# => 3500 rows (701.6ms)
```

By using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `WHERE NOT`, DB scans the table in a very different way. `WHERE NOT` loops over all rows in `assethistories` where `assethistories.asset_id` do not match all existing `assets.id`.

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` queries the records from the joined-table(`assethistories` and `assets` as a big one table) where the rows have `null` value in `asset.id` column, which is much more efficient.